# How to assign column headers if first row contains missing data

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to assign column headers to `df` using `df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

However some of my data has missing values in the first row, and assigning more column headers than columns in first row gives error. How to I assign header in this case without dropping the first row?

Example:

```
    No_hat     |         |
    green_hat  |  green  |   1
    red_hat    |  red    |   2

    df.columns = ['Hat', 'Color', 'quantity']

    Hat       |   Color   | quantity
-------------------------------------
    No_hat    |   Null    |  Null
    green_hat |   green   |  1
    red_hat   |   red     |  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with

```
df=df.T.reset_index().T
df.columns=['Hat', 'Color', 'quantity']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in case if anyone runs into the same issue.

When reading the file use `pd.read_csv(df.csv, names=['Hat', 'Color', 'Quantity'])` will automatically replace missing values with null and assigns column headers.